# Testing csv file stored in memory using unittest django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, csv, testing

I'm getting an error when trying to write to a csv file. Here's my two scripts:

Tasks.py

```
def get_data():

          customer = Customer.objects.all()
          csvfile = StringIO.StringIO()
          csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

          for i in customers:
              csvwriter.writerow([str(i.phone_number)])

          return csvfile
```

In tests.py:

```
    with open(get_data().getvalue(), 'rb') as myfile:
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(myfile.read().splitlines())]
        print data
```

This is the error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '999999999\r\n'
```

Where '999999999' is what should be written in the file.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you trying to open it at all? It's not a file. `get_data` is a StringIO object which you can read directly.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `get_data()` function doesn't return a file but a `StringIO` object. You don't need to `open()` it, you can just read it like this:

```
myfile = get_data().getvalue()
data = [row for row in csv.reader(myfile.splitlines())]
print data
```